# modules over group algebra which has free submodules

Tags: modules

M and M' are modules over the group algebra $kG$ and M $\subset$ M' (submodule). Assume that M is free. Does rank(M) less or equal rank(M')?
By rank(M') I mean a "minimal number of generators".

Comment: Br rank M' I mean a minimal number of generators (as a module).